# Create a file for each item in an array and write content for each item in another array?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

When I run the program it creates the files, but it loops the content of the files 3 times per file instead of looping through once. I believe it's how my for-loops are set up.

How would I correct the program below to create a file for each item in one array, `fileNameAry`, and fill the first line of the new file with content from another array, `fileContentAry`, with 3 additional lines after per file (4 lines per file).

What would be the best way to ensure that each file only has the 4 lines required and if this code could be better organized or looped more efficiently, how would I go about doing that?

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package createfileloop;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

/**
 *
 * @author DeveloperJC
 */
public class CreateFileLoop {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{  
    String[] fileNameAry = new String[]{
        "FirstFile.txt","SecondFile.txt","ThirdFile.txt"
    };
    String[] fileContentAry = new String[]{
        "First File","Second File","Third File"
    };
    int i,k;
        for(i=0; i<fileNameAry.length; i++){
            PrintStream fileStream = new PrintStream(new File("C:/Users/DeveloperJC/Desktop/"+fileNameAry[i]));
            for(k=0; k<fileContentAry.length; k++){
                fileStream.println("docname="+fileContentAry[k]);
                fileStream.println("2ndLine= Second Line");
                fileStream.println("3rdLine= Third Line");
                fileStream.println("4thLine= Fourth Line");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is wrong?

Comment: Updated the question: Best way to ensure each file only has 4 lines and after 4 lines, create the next file.

Comment: You might need to `close()` your `fileStream` after the second loop. You might prefer to use a for-each loop. And I believe you should ask this question on the [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) stack.

Answer (score 1):

Dont run `2 for` loops , it creates the problem.

since both the `string array` has same `size` so use `one for` loop and

access the `element` using the correspodning `array` name.

see the modified code below. hope it solves your problem.

```
for(i=0; i<fileNameAry.length; i++){
            PrintStream fileStream = new PrintStream(new File("C:/Users/DeveloperJC/Desktop/"+fileNameAry[i]));

                fileStream.println("docname="+fileContentAry[i]);
                fileStream.println("2ndLine= Second Line");
                fileStream.println("3rdLine= Third Line");
                fileStream.println("4thLine= Fourth Line");

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

For each file you are iterating over the `for(k=0; k<fileContentAry.length; k++){` **3 times**, and each time you are doing:

```
 fileStream.println("docname="+fileContentAry[i]);
 fileStream.println("2ndLine= Second Line");
 fileStream.println("3rdLine= Third Line");
 fileStream.println("4thLine= Fourth Line");
```

3 iterations * 4 lines each = 12 lines printed.